# "Failed to execute 'getImageData' 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data." for Dummies

Tags: windows, video-processing

When I try to play videos on several sites, I get the message

```
"Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': 
 The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data."
```

Every solution I have found -- and not just on Stackoverflow --i s written for developers who are trying to add something to Chrome or do I do not know what.

The answers are interesting for a bystander like myself, but they all involve making corrections in some code.  I am using a Chrome spinoff, Slimjet, running on Windows 10. Do any of you have a suggestion as to what I can do on an end-user level?

Thanks.... Ron

Answer (score 0):

> *"When I try to play videos on several sites..."*

You're not exactly "playing" the videos though, more like "recording" them if you involve `Canvas`. It's a content-protection issue (*eg:* protects those premium-view type companies and everyone else).

> *"Do any of you have a suggestion as to what I can do on an end-user level?"*

The video data must appear to be coming from your own domain (site) for the Canvas to work.

**Option 1**: Copy the required video file to your own space (where your HTML page is located).

**Option 2**: Use PHP code (if possible) to "proxy" the link. This means your `<video>` tag source is the PHP script link, and that same PHP script itself feeds the video data. Now browser is fooled into thinking video data is coming from somewhere on your server.

HTML video tag code:

```
<video id="myVid" preload="true">
  <source crossorigin="anonymous" src="http://www.yoursite.com/proxy_video.php">
</video>
```

PHP code (inside "`proxy_video.php`"):

```
<?php

$filename = "https://www...your_video_link";
$fp = fopen($filename, 'rb'); // open file pointer
$music = fpassthru($fp); // dump file stream to http
fclose($fp);

?>
```